# XML validation when in a secure environment

Tags: xml, xsd

I receive an XML document on a severely secure server. The document contains schema qualifiers that refer to www.w3.org.  The documents are failing validation because w3 is not reachable. This is happening in a utility beyond my control.

What are the alternatives to lobbying Infosec to allow a hole to be poked into the firewall?

Comment: Great question.  I've answered it before; see the duplicate link.   Let me know if you have further questions not answered there.  Thanks.